# Jhipster: Making a WAR file with client-configurable Datasource

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

My development team is working on a web application and has assigned me to research on how to make a client-side WAR file with a configurable Datasource.

This is the first commercial project of ours:

Language: Java / JavaScript(jQuery and AngularJS) / HTML / CSS

Database: MySQL

Development Tool: IntelliJ

Automation System: Gradle

Application Generator: JHipster

Version Control: SourceTree

At this time, our client has agreed to simply deploying the app on his own Amazon Web Server's MySQL database using an executable file (currently, a WAR file) delivered by us in a safe USB.

So far, the WAR file can be made with JHipster and deployed with no issue on our internal server. However, we did hard-code all the database-connection (JDBC) stuffs in a YML file under src/main/resources/config.

Naturally, our client has a database with totally different schema, usernames, and passwords. And the WAR file we are about to give him cannot be executed unless the datasource specs in there match his.

Because source codes cannot be extracted from a WAR, the client is not going to modify the datasource from his end. At the same time, he does not fancy giving us datasource information.

Thus, we are to come up with, quote, **an executable file which allows him to configure the datasource the first time it is executed on his AWS**.

Is there a way we can achieve this while not straying too far from the current deployment method (WAR file)?

Comment: 'Client-side WAR file' is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: So I suspect. I was even thinking if JAR file would be the answer, but then it would mean making the application offline

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific to JHipster here, it's purely a Spring Boot question. You can either provide an application-prod.yml external to your war file or keep it internal but use placeholders referring to environment variables defined in your client server.

For more details, read the Spring Boot doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html